# What are best practices regarding the deployment of Play code from a git repo to production?

Tags: playframework

Back in the days we use to deploy java code in a webserver like Tomcat or Jboss as an EAR or War file. What are best practices regarding the deployment of Play code?

**Discussion**

One option is to deploy the code using git and subsequently issue `play start`. If have checked [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying) documentation, but it is not clear to me how a full street looks like from the code in a git repository to running it in production.

Code in repository > create jar > publish to maven > deploy on server > how to run it? `play start`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Play! you don't need Tomcat neither JBoss. You will not have a war or an EAR file. You will have a standalone application ready to be use.

Play! is a kind of full-stack framework. Using `play dist` (or `activator dist`), will produce a zip file containing all jar files needed to run your application. It's also possible to produce a tar.gz, deb or rpm files.

So basically :

Code in repository > activator dist > myapp-1.0.zip created in target/universal folder > deploy myapp-1.0.zip on server > unzip the archive > myapp-1.0/bin/myapp to start your application